# Product formula for $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics

How to prove the following identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{2k+1}$$

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: Try expanding $(1+x^2)^n$. Then integrate, and put $x=i$

Comment: Try with induction first, should work out just fine (if it's true).

Comment: I have tried. But I can't prove this by induction

Answer (score 3):

Expanding $(1-x^2)^n$ we obtain
$$
(1-x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k}x^{2k}\binom{n}{k}.
$$
Then integrate the right hand side in $[0,1]$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\int_0^kx^{2k}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}.
$$
Then, for the left hand side set $x=\sin t$, and this, together with integration by parts, provides
\begin{align}
I_{n}&=\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^n\,dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n+1}t\,dt=\cos^{2n}t\,\sin t\big|_0^{\pi/2}
+2n\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n-1}t\sin^2 t\,dt\\
&=2n\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n-1}t\,dt-2n\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n+1}t\,dt=2nI_{n-1}-2nI_n,
\end{align}
which in turn provides the recursion relation
$$
I_{n}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{n-1}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}I_{n-2}=\prod_{k=0}^n
\frac{2k}{2k+1},
$$
as $I_0=1$. Therefore

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\prod_{k=0}^n
\frac{2k}{2k+1}.
$$

Comment: thank you Yiorgos S. Smyrlis